# Why does casting a string as float in PHP change the value?

Tags: php, string, casting, floating-point

Why does casting a decimal string as float change the value by a fraction of the last decimal place?

For example, I have:

```
class API_something{
    public function __construct($id, $name, $rank, $weight){
        $this->id = (int)$id;
        $this->name = strtolower($name);
        $this->rank = (int)$rank;
        $this->weight = floatval($weight);
    }
}
```

this object gets instantiated with a string passed to `$weight`. this is ultimately `json_encode`'d and values are as such:

```
{
    "weight": 81.770399999999995, 
    "id": 6, 
    "rank": 1, 
    "name": "ommitted"
}
```

I know I can use `number_format` or `round` to get it back to 4 decimal places, but both functions return a string.

Is there not a way to convert the original string to a float variable without PHP changing the value?

Comment: Working with floats does stuff like this

Comment: Actually, i can't recreate this?

Comment: var_dump(floatval($str)); => float 81.7704 ?

Comment: i'll update my question with my actual code. not sure if it would matter, but the value is a property of an object that eventually gets json encoded

Comment: See the big red warning on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: thanks @watcher . that definitely is applicable. that makes this feel flawed. is there no workaround? it's not the end of the world that i use number_format or round instead and just end up with a string, but i can't help but to think there's a way around...